# Can't generate x64 version of apks in my project

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, arm64

According to the new Play Store policy * that will take effect in August * I need to ensure that my app provides not only the 32-bit version, but also a 64-bit version, but when I try to generate that version through NDK, I always get the same libs. After trying and trying and trying, I just received an apk without any kind of "lib" folder.

I've tried to set NDK with abiFilters on gradle and got no changes...

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myproject.supermidia"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 20192201
    versionName "2.4"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify - does your app actually contain any native libraries _now_? Because the gradle snippet you've posted doesn't really have anything to do with building native code. If your app (including any dependencies it bundles) is written purely in java/kotlin then there's no need for you to do anything.

Comment: No, but it is worth remembering that I made several attempts and in my original code (before making all such attempts) I had inside the folder "libs" 2 libraries: armeabi and armv7 (something like that).
Currently as I removed a lot of things (like NDK and deleted the output and app-release folders) I may have affected it all. Can I clarify? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In order to build for ARM (and the `x86` emulator), the splits should look alike this. `x86_64` might be a little useless, because the `x86_64` emulator is slow and there is no hardware I'd be aware of ...

```
android {

    defaultConfig {

        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE", "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions"
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86"
            universalApk true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I'm a bit confused ... In the excerpt you posted appear terms that have never been in my, like: cmake and split or externalNativeBuild ... Will this affect? I have not yet had access to my mac to perform the tests, but I will go as soon as possible. Thank you.