# How to create android apk in 64 bit

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout

i have try to create android apk in 64 bit using below code.

```
buildTypes {
release {
    ndk {
        abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a"
    }
}
```

but not work for me.

Comment: @GovindParashar instead of writing comment you can flag question as duplicate

Comment: @barbsan but it's duplicate, also answered similar queston [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56351289/549372). configuration `ndk` is generally obsolete.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I'm afraid you didn't get my comment... Govind only wrote a comment without flagging question as duplicate

Comment: @MartinZeitler one need 15rep to flag, but Govind **didn't flag** the question - your auto-generated comment is different than Govind's comment

Comment: @barbsan thought it was a higher limit; however, with these two possible duplicates it should be possible to build for ARM64 ...whether with `nkdbuild` or with `cmake`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler seems that you thought of close-voting privilege which requires 3k rep. Can we stop this offtopic? I just wanted let Govind know that writing comment "Possible duplicate *{some url}*" is not the same as flagging as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Please try this following:

```
buildTypes 
{
    release 
    {

           ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }
}
```

Please follow this link and you will have to put .so files for 32/64 bit architecture:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit